# How to configure Docker to use a HTTP proxy for only one registry, not all of them

Tags: docker, http-proxy

At my job, we have internal services that can only be reached over a HTTP proxy. One such service is our internal Docker registry. I'm unable to communicate with this registry because my Docker daemon isn't configured to use a HTTP proxy.

If I do configure my Docker daemon to use the company HTTP proxy, I can push/pull images from the internal registry, but I'm now unable to communicate with any other registries. Changing the HTTP proxy environment variables and restarting my entire Docker daemon several times per day is a massive hassle and waste of time.

Basically what I need to do is configure Docker to use a HTTP proxy to communicate with one registry, but not all the other ones.

Is it possible to configure Docker this way, or is it all or nothing?

Comment: your proxy can't access the internet ? you can try to use the NO_PROXY env variable to exclude some domains, like NO_PROXY=registry.hub.docker.com

Comment: @Lk77 It can, but since it's behind big, bulky, bloated enterprise firewall it randomly seems to block a bunch of stuff, including the public Docker repositories. This makes it unusable for anybody working with Docker.

Comment: You can even do wildcard like NO_PROXY=*.docker.com,*.docker.io , it's perhaps more future proof than using the full domain

Comment: @Lk77 That would probably work, I had forgotten about `NO_PROXY`. However, it seems kind of upside down to do it this way. I'll have to add every other registry I use to the NO_PROXY list, and if I ever need to use a different proxy server for a different registry, I'm screwed.

Comment: Yes but docker don't allow to do the opposite sadly. You can use the file version instead of env variable (`~/.docker/config.json`), you can configure each proxy separately

Comment: @Lk77 I don't think the Docker configuration in my home directory has any effect on the Docker daemon and if it uses a HTTP proxy to fetch images.